# timing issue on method calls in actionscript 2.0 XML onLoad() function

Tags: xml, actionscript

I am brand new to actionscript and I am writing code for a network appliance that only supports ActionScript 2.0.

I am trying to read an XML feed and extract two pieces of text data from the feed (summary and details) then display them as two separate TextFields, resizing and repositioning the TextFields once I know how long each of them are.

I have successfully extracted the values from the feed and populated the TextFields using the XML onLoad() method. At the end of the onLoad() method I thought I could just call my class's private resizeSummary() method to do this, but for reasons that I clearly don't understand within the onLoad() method I can't seem to get my resizeSummary() methods called.

I would make the call to resizeSummary() later in the code, but that doesn't seem to matter because the onLoad() isn't being called until after everything else is done. So there appears to be a timing issue that I don't know how to control.

The simplest solution would be if I could figure out how to get my resizeSummary() method called in the xml onLoad() function event.

The second simplest solution would be if I could be notified when the onLoad() has been completed so I can resize the TextFields.

a code snippet from my class appears on the bottom of this posting.

```
class Foo {
// constructor
function Foo() {
  initSummaryTextField();
  getData();
}

private function getData() {
  var xmlData = new XML();
  xmlData.onLoad = function(success:Boolean): Void {
    if (success) {
      var summary:String = '';

      // successfully extracted summary text at this point and assigned value
      // to TextField .text variable. So I am good to here. 

      // THIS CALL NEVER SEEMS TO BE MADE EVEN THOUGH TRACE STATEMENT
      // IMMEDIATELY PRECEEDING IT DOES.
      trace("About to call resizeSummary()");
      this.resizeSummary();
    }
  }
  xmlData.load("URL TO SERVICE");
}


private function initSummaryTextField() {
  // do stuff here to create new TextField() for summary
}
private function resizeSummary() {
  trace("calling resizeSummary");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try swapping

```
this.resizeSummary();
```

for

```
resizeSummary();
```

`this` is referring to the onLoad function so the scope isn't at class level anymore.

Comment: If I remove the 'this.' from the resizeSummary() call within the onLoad() function definition the script doesn't compile. I'm using the mtasc ubuntu compiler and the error message I get is type error Unknown variable resizeSummary.

Answer (score 1):

for the annonymous onLoad() function defined in my class you apparently don't have visibility into the class methods and variables.

So what I did was the following. I added a thisObject local variable that references 'this' and can be accessed within the annonymous function.

```
// ADDED THIS LINE TO CREATE A REFERENCE TO this OBJECT. Then withing my annonymous function I can reference thisObject internally.
var thisObject:Foo = this;

xmlData.onLoad = function(success:Boolean): Void {
  if (success) {
  var summary:String = '';

  // successfully extracted summary text at this point and assigned value
  // to TextField .text variable. So I am good to here. 

  // THIS CALL NEVER SEEMS TO BE MADE EVEN THOUGH TRACE STATEMENT
  // IMMEDIATELY PRECEEDING IT DOES.
  trace("About to call resizeSummary()");
  thisObject.resizeSummary();
}
```

}